# Is it possible to write log filters in Java?

Tags: logstash

Is there any way to write a part of my log filtering logic in Java (natively or via some 3rd-party filter plugin)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an addon to do that https://github.com/fandrei/logstash-filter-java
Install it into logstash and run filters written in Java.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Open Source library MgntUtils that provides several utils, among them extraction of stacktrace from exception and optional filtering based on user configured package prefix. It could be very effectively used for filtering and shortening stacktraces in the log and make it by far better readable and much shorter. Here is a link to an article that explains the utilities in the library as well as provides links to Maven Central source and github: [Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman?trk=mp-reader-card). The library comes with well written Javadoc and source code